# Binary Tree diff of sum of nodes at odd and sum of nodes at even

Tags: java, binary-tree

How can I write the function to return the difference of the sum of values of nodes at odd height and the sum of values of nodes at even height. Considering the root node is at height 1 for a binary tree

**input:**

```
                                      1
                              2                3
                          4        5       6        7
                      8     9  10    11  12  13   14  15
```

Output: -74 Explanation :

```
[ (1 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 ) - (2 + 3 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15) = -74 ]
```

Code:

```
public static int diff(Node n) {
    if (n == null)
        return 0;
    return Sum(n) - Sum(n.left) - Sum(n.right);

}
public static int Sum(Node root) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (root == null) {
        return sum;
    }
    sum = sum + root.data;
    if (root.left != null) {
        sum = sum + Sum(root.left.left) + Sum(root.left.right);
    }
    if (root.right != null) {
        sum = sum + Sum(root.right.left) + Sum(root.right.right);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I have given this solution but not selected... I don't know whats wrong with this.

Comment: @KDiTraglia - Looks a lot like Java.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static int Sum(Node root) {

    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return root.data-Sum(root.left)-Sum(root.right);
}
```

This is easiest and smartest way i found the solution

Answer (score 2):

Here solution is explained using recusrsion in short..

Negate all levels under the current one (the level of the current node) and you do that on each step of the recursion.

```
sum[l1] – (sum[l2] – (sum[l3] – (sum[l4] – … = sum[l1] – sum[l2] + sum[l3] – sum[l4]…
```

www.crazyforcode.com/binary-tree-diff-sum-even-nodes-sum-odd-nodes/

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
public static int diff(Node n) {
    return sumtree(Node n, 1);
}

public static int sumtree(Node n, int level) {

   if (n == null) return 0;

   if (level % 2 == 0) { 
      return sumtree(n.left, level + 1) + sumtree(n.right, level +1 ) - n.value;
   } else {
      return sumtree(n.left, level + 1) + sumtree(n.right, level + 1) + n.value;
   }
}
```

Add values on odd level numbers (1, 3, 5 7...), subtract on even (2, 4, 6, 8...).

Answer (score 0):

The approach I took was to first find a way of adding all of the leaves, then just add a "level factor" if the level is even you you add otherwise you subtract. This may look similar to others but I find it cleaner.

On ANSI C

```
int diffOddAndEven(Node *root)
{
    return sumLevel(root, 0);
}

int sumLevel(Node *root, int level)
{
    int sum=0;
    int levelFactor = level%2 ? -1 : 1;

    if(!root)
        return 0;

    sum = root->value * levelFactor;

    sum += sumLevel(root->left, level+1);
    sum += sumLevel(root->right, level+1);

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my solution

```
traverse(root,1);  //1 is passed since we want oddlevelsum - evenlevelsum,pass -1 for opposite

int traverse(Tree* root,int level){

    if(root==NULL)return 0;
    return (level*root->data)+ traverse(level*-1,root->left_node)
       + traverse(level*-1,root->right_node);

}
```